# Change button style in Universal Windows Platform

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10, win-universal-app

I've tried to make a simple C# UWP application and I don't know how to remove the gray background when my mouse is over the button.

How I do that?

(remember: it's an UWP for Windows 10 platform , not Windows Phone 8.1 or WPF)

[image: The simple button]

[image: the button when my mouse is over]

Comment: You need to edit the style source - There is a story board attached which is changing the color to gray - you might want to change that color to transparent. I will give you a detailed answer with screenshots soon.

Comment: Thank you! I'm a noob and I don't know how to do that

Comment: Pls upload the xaml code behind your button. I can not see if  you are  using a Appbarbutton or a "normal" button. I guess it's the "normal" one isn't it?

Comment: Yes it's a normal button.

Comment: <Button x:Name="button" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="124,201,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="150" Width="169" Foreground="#00000000" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///512.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Rightclick in the Solution Explorer and add a new item of kind "ResourceDictionary"
2. Copy the Default Style of the Button you can find it on this webpage, you need to scroll down a little bit: 
   [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709909.aspx)

Then insert it in your ResourceDictionary.xaml format should look like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary><Style></Style></ResourceDictionary>
```

3. Give the Style a key like this:

```
<Style x:Key="MyCustomButton"></Style>
```

4. Go to App.xaml edit it by adding the Resource Dictionary like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The Source of the ResourceDictionary is the Name of your ResourceDictionary file.

5. Then add the style to your button like this: `<Button Style="{StaticResource  MyCustomButton}"></Button>`
6. Last but not least go back to your ResourceDictionary and delete the following code lines you see in the Screenshot or comment it out like i did:
   [image: Edit your style]

There is a more easy solution if you use Blend for Visual Studio there you can edit this stuff more quickly but to keep the structure and for learning it the solution above is the better one.

Comment: Did he just say "quicklier"? Yes, he did! +1