# Universal App W10 Change standard styles

Tags: windows, default, store, universal

how can i change the standarad style setting from a Windows Store App.
For example they ["grey box" hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3vfi.png)

For more detail: I want no hover when i point on a button...

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the standard style of the button. You can find the default style [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709909.aspx), then follow the step [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32920858/1279342)