# Template 10 : HamburgerButton Visibility Issue

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, template10

I am trying to create a UI like this for my app

[image: Expected Hamburger Ui]

But instead I am getting this:

[image: Getting this]

Here is My Xaml Code:

```
     <Controls:HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons >
            <!--  mainpage button  -->
            <Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo >            
          <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.jpg"/>
          </Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo>
        </Controls:HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons>
    </Controls:HamburgerMenu>
```

The button is still visible.Also is there any way to remove the white selected highlight colour appearing on the Logo.Thanks in advance.
Also With this code:

```
             <controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="Menu"
                HamburgerBackground="#FFD13438"
                HamburgerForeground="White"
                NavAreaBackground="#FF2B2B2B"
                NavButtonBackground="#FFD13438"
                SecondarySeparator="White"
                NavButtonForeground="White" />
```

The Hamburger panel is not changing.Is it a bug?

Edit: The button is hamburger button and the white color is this one:
[image]

Comment: "The button is still visible" which button you are referring here? and the "white selected highlight color" where is that in the image provided? Also, Logo.jpg is the triangle upside down? Please elaborate the question or provide a Minimal viable problem application so that we can figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is going to be a long answer but bear with me.

---

### Getting things cleared

1. your custom hamburger Icon shows up in towards the right because you might be using the Hamburger Template in `T10` which has a `shell.xaml` view for the hamburger behavior of the app.
2. The `shell.xaml` replaces the current window and each `Page` or `Frame` is hosted in the `shell.xaml`. This ways you'll be able to have a hamburger menu in all your pages without having to add a new control in each view. If this is not your requirement, I would advise you to use `Minimal Template` and then add the `Hamburger Control` from the `T10` or use a `splitview` if you want to create the boilerplate stuff for yourself.
3. If you want to edit the view of the Hamburger Icon, you can simply go to the `shell.xaml` and add edit the icon or the control in any way.

---

### Your solution:

1. You can edit the hamburger icon from the `T10` project source code provided on GitHub to make it look like the Triangle and then import the modified class with Resource Dictionary or the dll.
2. To avoid the highlight and all the button like behavior of the Hamburger Icon on `Tapped`, `PointerPressed`, `mouse Over` and others, consider creating a style that helps you to do so under it's `VisualStates`.

### What I would advise

Instead of going and modifying a stable library, rather why don't you create a `Minimal Template` project and then add your own `Splitview`. That being said, you can also start of with the `Hamburger Template` and in the `shell.xaml` you remove the `<Controls:HamburgerMenu/>` and replace it with a `splitview` instead. That would be far more convenient to work with as compared to modifying your `T10` source code from GitHub or even even starting off with a minimal template and creating the boiler plate stuff for yourself. If you need any help feel free to mention in the comments section.

For the button highlights, you will have to edit the style for it. for more information refer, [This query here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920211/change-button-style-in-universal-windows-platform). and apply this for the hamburger menu icon. Please note, the target might be an app bar button instead of the button. make sure you set the correct `targetType`